# label not updating in setter

Tags: iphone, ios5, uilabel, settext

ok so this problem is kinda weird because the NSLog I have right in front of the line of code that should be printing out the text is returning the correct value.

Here's the code:

```
-(void)setCurrentDate:(UILabel *)currentDate
{

NSInteger onDay = 1; //because if it's today, you are on day one, not zero... no such thing as a day zero

//get the nubmer of days left
if( [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"StartDate"] ){ //if there is something at the userdefaults
    onDay = [self daysToDate:[NSDate date]];
}//otherwise, onDay will just be one

self.theCurrentNumberOfDaysSinceStart = onDay;

NSLog(@"On day: %d", onDay); //this is returning the correct values....

//print it out on the label
[currentDate setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"On day: %d", onDay]];//echoes out the current day number 

}
```

So when the app first launches, everything is fine. The label updates and everything. The problem arises when I hit a button that basically grabs a new date. In the process, it runs this:

```
    //need to reload the "on day" label now
    [self setCurrentDate:self.currentDate];
    //and the "days left" label
    [self setDaysLeft:self.daysLeft];
```

Again, I'm thinking this should all be correct because the NSLog is returning the correct stuff. I'm thinking that the problem is with the last line in the first block of code I showed... the line with the setText.

thanks for all your help!

cheers,
Matt

Comment: Can you confirm that `currentDate` is not `nil` when calling `setText:`

Comment: Also what are you trying to achieve with this `[self setCurrentDate:self.currentDate];`? I think it would make more sense to just have a method that you call to set the text value not reassign the same object to itself and as a side effect have the date be set.

Comment: yeah... it was NULL... but 1) I don't see why because isn't it the label itself? and 2) it worked the first time so why not the other times? =/

Comment: When you say the first time do you mean after loading from interface builder?

Comment: I mean when the app first launches

Comment: Is this `UILabel` created in a `nib`?

Comment: in a storyboard... but yeah. I'm starting to think that maybe after I call the setCurrentDate method once (on start up), it sets it for good.. meaning I can't change it... would that be a possibility?

Comment: Yep, that was it lol ... I wonder why it stops letting me change the label after I use the setter for it once... hm....

Comment: The problem is you have no reference to it - see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you used a nib**

When the nib loads and establishes all of it connections it... (From the [Resource Programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html))

> looks for a method of the form `set` *OutletName:* and calls it if such a method is present

Therefore the nib will load and call `setCurrentDate:` passing in the unarchived `UILabel` as the parameter

In your method you configure the `UILabel` using the **local** reference passed into the method

```
[currentDate setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"On day: %d", onDay]];
```

You at no point actually store a reference to this `UILabel` in an ivar, so technically you have leaked the label and as you have not set the ivar `currentDate` it will be initialised to `nil`. This is the danger of overriding a setter with an incorrect implementation.

At some point in your method you should be setting your ivar to the passed in variable. A normal setter would look like this

```
- (void)setCurrentDate:(UILabel *)currentDate;
{
    if (_currentDate != currentDate) {
        [_currentDate release];
        _currentDate = [currentDate retain];
    }
}
```

**But**

In your example I would not worry about this at all I would instead change this

```
//need to reload the "on day" label now
[self setCurrentDate:self.currentDate];
```

to something like

```
[self updateCurrentDate];
```

The implementation would look something like:

```
- (void)updateCurrentDate;
{
    NSInteger onDay = 1;

    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"StartDate"]) {
        onDay = [self daysToDate:[NSDate date]];
    }

    self.theCurrentNumberOfDaysSinceStart = onDay;

    [self.currentDate setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"On day: %d", onDay]];
}
```

Comment: yeah and then do [self updateCurrentDate]; in the viewWillAppear. Already did that ;) I was just trying to figure out why it the setter wasn't doing it but it makes sense now. Thanks!